# Ansible how to parse JSON file contains comments, using slurp module

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

Trying to fetch a value from JSON file using slurp module. Able to fetch when JSON file has no comments. But when a file has a line commented getting an error.

JSON File:

```
{
    "domain":{
//           "name": "mwidomain" #Commented line
    },
    "storage": {
    "defaultFileStore": "local",
  }
}
```

Playbook:

```
  - name: slurp
    slurp:
      src: "/tmp/test.json"
    register: imported_config

  - name: Fetch storage type from config
    set_fact:
      current_storage_type: "{{ imported_config.content|b64decode |from_json |json_query(jmesquery) }}"
    vars:
      jmesquery: 'storage.defaultFileStore'
```

Error:

```
"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({u'current_storage_type': u'{{ imported_config.content|b64decode |from_json |json_query(jmesquery) }}'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 3 column 1 (char 17)\
```

**Note:** The same is working when the JSON file has no commented lines.

Comment: `//` not json comment. Also json does not have comment blocks

Comment: I understand JSON doesn't have comments. But in my case the config file allows comments and it is a JSON format.

Comment: Then it is not json and you need to use a parser which understands your file format. `from_json` understands json which does not have comments in its grammar.

Comment: Note that if your original format accepts comments as hashes (#) and since yaml is a strict superset of json, you can use `from_yaml` to parse your file in that situation. But it will not work with double slashes.

Comment: You are correct ```from_json``` doesn't understand. But still, for my node js application, it is a JSON syntax, with the ```regex_replace``` i am able to fetch the filed(may be not the right way).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of, `regex_findall`I am able to fetch the field. This may not the right way but I managed to get what needed.

Playbook:-

```
  - name: slurp
    slurp:
      src: "/tmp/test.json"
    register: imported_config

  - name: Fetch storage type from config
    set_fact:
      current_storage_type: "{{ imported_config.content | b64decode| regex_findall('\"defaultFileStore\"s*(.*)')| map('regex_replace', '[^A-Za-z0-9._-]', '')|list|join() }}"
```